# Xamarin android grouped notifications not replaced by collapsible summary

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

Expected / desired behaviour:

- The two notifications are grouped, collapsed and replaced by the summary notification. Expanding the summary notification should show both individual notifications.

Actual behaviour:

- The two notifications are grouped, collapsed, but not replaced by the summary.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentText("Notification Summary")
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
            .SetContentTitle("Title summary")
            .SetGroupSummary(true)
            .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentText("Notification a")
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
            .SetContentTitle("Title a")
            .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilderB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentText("Notification b")
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
            .SetContentTitle("Title b")
            .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);


var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
notificationManager.Notify(3, notificationBuilder.Build());
notificationManager.Notify(2, notificationBuilderB.Build());
notificationManager.Notify(1, summaryBuilder.Build());
```

Things I tried:

- Use NotificationManagerCompat instead of NotificationManager (doesn't help)
- Change the order of the `Notify` calls (interestingly, the summary does appear when notified first, but then gets overwritten by the next notification).
- Run on a different phone

Using

- Android 9 (or 8)
- Xamarin.Android v28.0.0.3
- Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0

Is my code wrong or is there a bug?

Comment: Turns out summary notifications don't replace the individual notifications. So `SetContentText` didn't work as expected. Apparently the summary uses `SetStyle` and `SetSummaryText`. See Wendy's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It caused by the `Notification ID` 1, 2, 3. `Notification ID` used for all notifications in this app. Reusing the notification ID prevents the creation of numerous different notifications as the user experiments with different notification settings -- each launch reuses and updates the same notification.

```
notificationManager.Notify(3, notificationBuilder.Build());
notificationManager.Notify(2, notificationBuilderB.Build());
notificationManager.Notify(1, summaryBuilder.Build());
```

If you want to replace by the summary notification, use the same `Notification ID` 1 with summary notification.

Please note, if you use the summary notification to replace with the same `Notification ID`, there is only one summary notification.

**Updated:**

> I want to see a collapsible summary, that when expanded shows both notification a and b. Sorry if it wasn't clear, I updated the question.

If you want to see more about Summery notification, you could use SetStyle to do that with BigTextStyle. I make a sample code for your reference.

```
Notification notificationA = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentText("Notification a")                           
                        .SetContentTitle("Title a")
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.star)
                        .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .Build();


            Notification notificationB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentText("Notification b")                           
                        .SetContentTitle("Title b")
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.star)
                        .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .Build();

            Notification notificationSummery = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().SetSummaryText("Summary Notification"))
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.star)
                        .SetGroup("GROUP_A")
                        .SetGroupSummary(true)
                        .Build();

            var notificationManager1 = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

            notificationManager1.Notify(1, notificationA);
            notificationManager1.Notify(2, notificationB);
            notificationManager1.Notify(3, notificationSummery);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this in the same order as above, and I get: first notification `a` is delivered, then notification `b` is delivered, then the summary notification overrides notification `a` (because it has the same id), and only notification `b` shows.
I want to see a collapsible summary, that when expanded shows both notification `a` and `b`. Sorry if it wasn't clear, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't know of `SetSummaryText`, which is what I needed in the end.